# How to get the name of the last column from the SQL table without traversing in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

My database contains 'n' number of columns.

For example:

```
     Name city phone number ..............,
```

Exactly I don't know about the total number of columns and name of the last column.

The name of the columns will be changed at run time (such as The name of columns are not constant fields).

```
#include <stdio.h> /* needed for vsnprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* needed for malloc-free */
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

char * sql = PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
int i = 0;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL);
printf(" PRAGMA: rc = %d\n", rc);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK )
{
  printf("Error: %s:Unable to Query the SQL Column from the table.\n", zErrMsg);  
}
else if(rc == SQLITE_OK)
{
      while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
      {
          int totCol = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
          for(i=0; i<totCol ;i++)
          {
               printf("Column-Name: %s\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i));
          }
     }
  }
```

Through the above pragma command, I am traversing the entire columns in the SQL table and found the name of the last column.

Is there any way to know the name of the last column without traversing the entire columns in the SQL table.

Note: I don't want to do the following things

1. Executing more than one SQL statement.
2. Traversing the entire columns to find the last column from the SQL table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can achieve this using the following as the basis :-

```
SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('table_name') ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

As described in [PRAGMA Statements - PRAGMA functions](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)